# Consulta MAX() en SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Hola tengo una duda con un ejercicio de **SQL** en el que me piden encontrar las piezas con peso máximo.

Tabla:

> PIEZA (codpie, nompie, color, peso, ciudad)

He pensado en las siguientes consultas pero no se si están bien:

**OPCIÓN 1:**

```
SELECT @maximo_peso = (SELECT MAX(peso) FROM piezas)
SELECT codpie FROM piezas WHERE peso = @maximo_peso;
```

---

**OPCIÓN 2:**

```
SELECT codpie, MAX(peso) as 'maximo' WHERE peso = maximo;
```

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Puedes mejorar tu pregunta con un ejemplo? si tienes unos datos de prueba, qué resultado esperarías obtener de la consulta, ver esa información sería muy útil para entender mejor el problema.

Answer (score 0):

La opción 2 nunca funcionaría porque no tienes definido `maximo`.
La opción 1 funciona pero puedes hacerlo en una sola sentencia:

```
SELECT codpie FROM piezas WHERE peso = (SELECT MAX(peso) FROM piezas);
```

`SELECT MAX(peso) FROM piezas` trae un solo resultado, que es el peso máximo entre todas las piezas que haya en la tabla, no importa cuantas sean. Por ejemplo si ese peso es 10, entonces sería como hacer así: `SELECT codpie FROM piezas WHERE peso = 10;`

Comment: No, traería todas las piezas que tengan el peso máximo, puede ser una o varias.

Comment: No, ahí lo edité para explicarlo.

Comment: Entonces puedes poner la respuesta como útil! :)